# XSL Copy Nodes based on Attribute Value (Like Search)

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have attached XML file and I want to copy only the node which attribute value is something, In my case AHC_. In each node any attribute has value starting with 'AHC_' copy that node and ignore other nodes.

I am trying with following XSL and condition is working but not copying the node.Could you please take a look and suggest?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="Schedules">
        <xsl:if test="Schedule[@ServiceName='MESAVisToolkit_RetentionProcessor']">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Sample XML:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Schedules>
    <Schedule OrganizationKey=" " ScheduleID="13" ServiceName="RetentionProcessor">
        <TimingXML>
            <days>
                <day ofWeek="-1">
                    <times>
                        <time>0200</time>
                    </times>
                </day>
            </days>
            <excludedDates/>
        </TimingXML>
    </Schedule>
    <Schedule OrganizationKey=" " ScheduleID="14" ServiceName="MESAVisToolkit_RetentionProcessor">
        <TimingXML>
            <days>
                <day ofWeek="-1">
                    <times>
                        <time>0300</time>
                    </times>
                </day>
            </days>
        </TimingXML>
    </Schedule>
    <Schedule OrganizationKey=" " ScheduleID="15" ServiceName="MailboxEvaluateAllAutomaticRules">
        <TimingXML>
            <days>
                <day ofWeek="-1">
                    <times>
                        <timeRange>
                            <range>0000-2359</range>
                            <interval>1</interval>
                            <onMinute>0</onMinute>
                        </timeRange>
                    </times>
                </day>
            </days>
            <excludedDates/>
        </TimingXML>
    </Schedule>
    <Schedule OrganizationKey=" " ScheduleID="16" ServiceName="MailboxEvaluateAllAutomaticRulesSubMin">
        <TimingXML>
            <days>
                <day ofWeek="-1">
                    <times>
                        <timeRange>
                            <range>0000-2359</range>
                            <interval>1</interval>
                            <onMinute>0</onMinute>
                        </timeRange>
                    </times>
                </day>
            </days>
        </TimingXML>
    </Schedule>
    <Schedule OrganizationKey=" " ScheduleID="51" ServiceName="AHC_001_01_0100_Get_Schedule">
        <TimingXML>
            <days>
                <day ofWeek="-1">
                    <times>
                        <timeRange>
                            <range>0000-2359</range>
                            <interval>5</interval>
                            <onMinute>0</onMinute>
                        </timeRange>
                    </times>
                </day>
            </days>
        </TimingXML>
    </Schedule>
    <Schedule OrganizationKey=" " ScheduleID="54" ServiceName="AHC_001_01_0200_Get_Schedule">
        <TimingXML>
            <days>
                <day ofWeek="-1">
                    <times>
                        <timeRange>
                            <range>0000-2359</range>
                            <interval>5</interval>
                            <onMinute>0</onMinute>
                        </timeRange>
                    </times>
                </day>
            </days>
        </TimingXML>
    </Schedule>
</Schedules>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Schedule OrganizationKey=" " ScheduleID="51" ServiceName="AHC_001_01_0100_Get_Schedule">
        <TimingXML>
            <days>
                <day ofWeek="-1">
                    <times>
                        <timeRange>
                            <range>0000-2359</range>
                            <interval>5</interval>
                            <onMinute>0</onMinute>
                        </timeRange>
                    </times>
                </day>
            </days>
        </TimingXML>
    </Schedule>
    <Schedule OrganizationKey=" " ScheduleID="54" ServiceName="AHC_001_01_0200_Get_Schedule">
        <TimingXML>
            <days>
                <day ofWeek="-1">
                    <times>
                        <timeRange>
                            <range>0000-2359</range>
                            <interval>5</interval>
                            <onMinute>0</onMinute>
                        </timeRange>
                    </times>
                </day>
            </days>
        </TimingXML>
    </Schedule>
</Schedules>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> condition is working but not copying the node.

That's not true. All `Schedule` nodes are copied, without condition. That's because your condition makes no sense. It makes no sense because it has nothing to do with what you said you want:

> In each node any attribute has value starting with 'AHC_' copy that
>   node

Even more importantly, it makes no sense because it is evaluated from the context of the parent `Schedules` element, not the individual `Schedule` nodes. Thus, if **any** `Schedule` child satisfies the condition, you will be applying templates to (i.e. copying) **all** of them.

To selectively copy only `Schedule` elements that satisfy some condition, you should structure your stylesheet as:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Schedules">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Schedule[--your condition goes here---]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```