# XSLT - copy listed nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to generate translation files that will hide some parameters based on different software version and customer. My other requirement is to sort the Param based on a generated list.

EDIT: I don't want to prepare a list of excluded nodes as the original set is dynamic and only the specified nodes if found should be copied.

Example source XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ns:ParameterElements AllowAdd="True" moreattributes xmlns:ns="http://www.somens.com/schema">
<ParameterFile>
    <Container>
        <Param Name="n1">
            ...
        </Param>
        <Param Name="sth1">
            ...
        </Param>
        <Param Name="toberemoved" ...>
            ...
        </Param>
    </Container>
</ParameterFile>
</ns:ParameterElements>
```

I did try plenty approach but this one seems to be closest [XSL Copy Nodes based on Attribute Value (Like Search)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41924861/xsl-copy-nodes-based-on-attribute-value-like-search)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="paramSortingList" select="('sth1','n1')"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ParameterFile/Container/Param">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*[name()=$paramSortingList]|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So this would be perfect for me as with one list I could copy the nodes in the order I need.

Unfortunately the presented solution does not work,

EDIT: my desired outcome:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ns:ParameterElements AllowAdd="True" moreattributes xmlns:ns="http://www.somens.com/schema">
<ParameterFile>
    <Container>
        <Param Name="sth1">
            ...
        </Param>
        <Param Name="n1">
            ...
        </Param>
    </Container>
</ParameterFile>
</ns:ParameterElements>
```

please note I don't want to prepare a list of excluded nodes as the set is dynamic and only the specified nodes if found should be copied.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the output you expect, please? Also note, the syntax `('sth1','n1')` is only valid in XSLT 2.0. Are you actually using an XSLT 2.0 processor? Thanks

Comment: Yes, I'm using XSLT 2.0 processor, you are right I had this before: <xsl:param name="paramSortingList" select="'paramName1,paramName2'"/> and it was working although without copying the selected nodes but all found nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming at least XSLT 2.0 you can simply use

```
<xsl:template match="ParameterFile/Container/Param[not(@Name = $paramSortingList)]"/>
```

in your stylesheet to ensure the `Param` elements not in your name sequence are not copied.

If you move to XSLT 3.0 as supported by Saxon 9.8 or Altova 2017 or 2018 you can shorten the whole to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="paramSortingList" select="('sth1','n1')"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template match="ParameterFile/Container/Param[not(@Name = $paramSortingList)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Unfortunately i get: starting XSLT process
Fail occurs on transformation.
Error : Variables cannot be used within this expression. XSLT 2.0 processor

Comment: Which processor do you use that gives that error? XSLT 2 and later allows variable references in patterns.

Comment: You are right Martin, I'm using .net c# xslt processor from System.Xml.Xsl; and I found out it's v1.0 not v2.0 as i was thinking. I will use 3rd party libs to integrate with v2.0 processor, thanks

Comment: I moved to Saxon 9.8 as you adviced, this solution is almost working, i get the copy of objects on list but there is no </Container> and </ParameterFile> closures

Comment: I have put the code I suggested into an XSLT 3 fiddle at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDbh and it shows the desired output. Processor there used is Saxon 9.8 HE, the .NET version. I doubt that the bug you have linked to causes any problems with the code suggested in this answer as it doesn't use any streaming while the problem I reported in that bug where caused in samples using streaming. If you still have problems then I think it is better you ask a new question with minimal but complete samples allowing others to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You are right Martin, it works! But when I tested this on a very big file every new param that was skipped produced a newline and I didn't see the closures. To remove the newlines i simply added <xsl:template match="*/text()[not(normalize-space())]" /> to your solution, many thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Using an XSLT 2.0 is the way to go here, as has been answered already, but if were interested in an XSLT 1.0 solution in the short-term, here is how you would do it (using some crude string manipulation)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="paramSortingList" select="'sth1,n1'"/>
<xsl:param name="paramSortingListPlus" select="concat(',', $paramSortingList, ',')"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ParameterFile/Container">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Param[contains($paramSortingListPlus, concat(',', @Name, ','))]">
        <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before($paramSortingListPlus, concat(',', @Name, ',')))" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```